Xen on EVE HVMLOADER missing
I am trying to use Xen Hypervisor on a rpi4b+. I am using LF's Edge Project EVE (based on Alpine Linux and Linuxkit) that includes Xen in a container. I got EVE 11.0.5 - LTS with Xen 4.15.0 running in my rpi4b+, but when i try to create a HVM DomU with xl create the next error appears:
xc: error:panic: xg_dom_core.c:206:failed to open file '/usr/lib/xen/boot/hvmloader': no such file or directory: Internal error. 
Does anyone know if this is a bug?
Maybe hvmloader is not included because it is not possible to create HVM DomU in rpi. I say that because when i use lscpu command the next parameters appears:
... Virtualization features: Hypervisor vendor: Xen Virtualization type: para  ...
and when i use the command xl info | grep xen_caps it only appears:
xen_caps     : xen-3.0-aarch64 xen-3.0-arm7
(Does this mean that only paravirtualization is enabled? If it is, how can i get full virtualization enabled?)
Thanks in advance
I tried to find any information about this missing HVMloader file, but did not get anything that explains why this is missing
